# Regarding black holes and the speed of light

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, photons, speed-of-light

Prior to a black hole reaching sufficient (size ) to stop radiating light (due to excessive gravity ) would the speed of radiation of light slow smoothly down to zero (as the hole draws closer to the critical size)

Comment: have a lool at the answer here  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/145110/ to get a feel of what is happening with the speed of light in general  relativity

Comment: I'm interested in the smoothness of the velocity change in the question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local speed of light, as measured in the coordinates of any inertial observer, is always the same. There is no change during the formation of a black hole.

The coordinate velocity of the speed of light could change during formation of a black hole, depending on what coordinates you're using. This is of little interest, because you can always make a coordinate velocity be whatever you like, by choosing the necessary coordinates. This is true regardless of whether there is a black hole or a gravitational field.